# MySQL how to check whether DB has performed rollback

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

Is there a log somewhere that I can check if my db did perform a rollback? The most ideal solution will be for me to find a log that tells me "DB performed a rollback at yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm because of xxxx reason." I am using Amazon RDS if that is hopefully any better.

I am trying to debug a problem and it will help me narrow down the issue if I know whether the db performed rollbacks during the time of incident.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the db performed" a rollback? The point of a rollback is to undo a single transaction and nothing more. They occur if a client, while in a transaction, issues a `ROLLBACK` statement or is disconnected prior to a `COMMIT` statement or implicit commit.  If you have the general query log enabled, you could track it by identifying every case of both such events. Rollbacks are often not written to the binlog, but can sometimes be.  Please describe your situation more thoroughly.

Comment: thanks for the response. I actually just want to know if there was indeed a rollback, and if so, at what time and perhaps even what was the last statement of the transaction executed.

Comment: also you can monitor `show status like 'com_rollback%'`